# Lookup library that retrieves values based on paths

Tags: java, dictionary, web.xml

I would like a library that works just like servlet mappings, without the servlet container. It should support concepts such as this:

```
/*        maps the default value
/exact    maps exact path maps
/prefix   maps any path that begins with "/prefix"
*.suffix  maps any paths that end with "suffix".
```

Imagine something like a `Map` that accepts string paths to fetch values. The library should also support some concept of priority, so if I add an exact path before a prefix, the test is against the `exact`, before checking the `prefix` paths. Naturally, I could write my own, but a boring linear search seems a bit dumb, especially as most paths will be exact patterns.

Does anyone know of a library that does something like this?

Comment: Can you give an example of a lookup call you would make to this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up righting my own little package that uses the chain of responsbility pattern. It groups exact matches that were added consecutively into a single link(not sure what eacch element in a cor is called) in the chain. All other types of mapping are single "links". The search invokes the chain until a value is returned ignoring the remainder of the chain.

Answer (score -1):

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) supports Ant-style globs in request path mappings. In your controller class (annotated with `@Controller`), you can specify your path pattern in [the RequestMapping annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) on your handler method like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/myPath/*.do")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("helloWorld");
        mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just using servlet mappings because it was the best example, however this is not intended for servlets or anything where a servlet container could do the job.